# add more information in realtime database after creating user record

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have my classes and javas codes, I would like to add more information in different activities linking with the user's registry data. How do I do that ? I just need this to build the app

Register Activity:

```
public class RegisterBasicInfo extends AppCompatActivity {



        private EditText nome;
        private EditText email;
        private EditText senha;
        private Button botaoCadastrar;
        private Usuario usuario;

        private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registerbasic_info);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_nome);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_email);
        senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cadastro_senha);
        botaoCadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_cadastrar);

        botaoCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
                usuario.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                usuario.setSenha(senha.getText().toString());
                cadastrarUsuario();

            }
        });

    }

        private void cadastrarUsuario () {

        autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                usuario.getEmail(),
                usuario.getSenha()
        ).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterBasicInfo.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterBasicInfo.this, "Sucesso ao cadastrar usuário", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String identificadorUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());
                    usuario.setId(identificadorUsuario);
                    usuario.salvar();

                    abrirLoginUsuario();

                } else {

                    String erro = "";
                    try {
                        throw task.getException();
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                        erro = "Escolha uma senha que contenha, letras e números.";
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                        erro = "Email indicado não é válido.";
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                        erro = "Já existe uma conta com esse e-mail.";
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterBasicInfo.this, "Erro ao cadastrar usuário: " + erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

        public void abrirLoginUsuario () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterBasicInfo.this,RegisterGender.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    }
```

My Class Users

```
public class Usuario {

    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private String sex;
    private String preferSex;

    public Usuario(){

    }

    public void salvar(){
        DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
        referenciaFirebase.child("usuarios").child( getId() ).setValue( this );
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }


    public String getPreferSex() {
        return preferSex;
    }

    public void setPreferSex(String preferSex) {
        this.preferSex = preferSex;
    }



}
```

so far everything is ok, but now that you add the sex with the button, it opens the screen but does not register

```
public class RegisterGender extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String password;
    User user;
    boolean male = true;
    private Button genderContinueButton;
    private Button maleSelectionButton;
    private Button femaleSelectionButton;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_gender);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("classUser");
        password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

        maleSelectionButton = findViewById(R.id.maleSelectionButton);
        femaleSelectionButton = findViewById(R.id.femaleSelectionButton);
        genderContinueButton = findViewById(R.id.genderContinueButton);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //By default male has to be selected so below code is added

        femaleSelectionButton.setAlpha(.5f);
        femaleSelectionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);


        maleSelectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                maleButtonSelected();
            }

            Usuario user = new Usuario();




        });

        femaleSelectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                femaleButtonSelected();
            }
            Usuario user = new Usuario();

        });

        genderContinueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openPreferenceEntryPage();
            }
            Usuario user = new Usuario();


        });

    }

    public void maleButtonSelected() {
        male = true;
        maleSelectionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"));
        maleSelectionButton.setAlpha(1.0f);
        femaleSelectionButton.setAlpha(.5f);
        femaleSelectionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    }

    public void femaleButtonSelected() {
        male = false;
        femaleSelectionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"));
        femaleSelectionButton.setAlpha(1.0f);
        maleSelectionButton.setAlpha(.5f);
        maleSelectionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    }


    public void openPreferenceEntryPage() {
        mDatabase.child("usuarios").push().setValue(user);
        String ownSex = male ? "male" : "female";
        user.setSex(ownSex);
        //set default photo
        String defaultPhoto = male ? "defaultMale" : "defaultFemale";
        user.setProfileImageUrl(defaultPhoto);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterGenderPrefection.class);
        intent.putExtra("password", password);
        intent.putExtra("classUser", user);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not understand your question. I think Your question is that You create user in firebase Auth and You also think to remain data can add in real time .

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have the activity record, that's right, I can manually insert data into firebase, then I have the actvity gender I wanted to insert data into the realtime database from a new activity

Comment: I'm not able to insert data into realtime firebase from a new activity

Comment: I managed to read the DatabaseReference tutorial and put more child on the line, hard to see that?

Comment: DatabaseReference furosRef = firebaseRef
            .child(idUsuario.toString())
            .child("vhykFsTJMhaCd6jkBd3oXpmYoiH2Thu Jan 10 22:54:24 GMT-02:00 2019")
             .child("furos")
            .child("Thu Jan 10 22:54:51 GMT-02:00 2019");